# Images not loading after updating to Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image

**EDIT
I did a bit of debugging and changed the name "penguin" to an image file that doesn't exist, and the strange thing is that sometimes when i compile it I will get the square icon with the x , meaning that the file with that given name was not located, but other times, this error box will not even show up. The strange thing is that even if this error box does not show up (meaning the program did not try to locate the image file), the hit detection still woks and the "invisible" penguin can still die
**

I recently updated my Xcode from 6.4.? to 7.2.1. Upon doing so, some of my images will no longer load. The strange thing is that the images will (upon compiling the game on the simulator) occasionally load, and occasionally not show up. Additionally, none of my SpriteKit particle emitters are loading either.

My images are all within the supporting files folder and are labeled as "imageName@2x.png". Additionally, the images are all instantiated/ inserted into the game programatically.

Esentially I am creating a SKSpriteNode called hero as so:

```
characterName = @"penguin";
hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:characterName];
hero.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*0.5, self.frame.size.height*0.5);
hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:hero.texture size:hero.texture.size];
hero.physicsBody.dynamic=YES;
hero.physicsBody.friction=NO;
hero.physicsBody.allowsRotation=NO;
hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = heroCategory;
hero.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory;
hero.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
hero.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
hero.alpha = 0;
[mainLayer addChild:hero];
```

Then to make the hero visable, I later change the alpha of the SKSpriteNode upon starting the game:

```
-(IBAction)startGame:(id)sender{
hero.alpha = 1;
.....
}
```

I make many of my other images in a similar way.

An example of what will happen is that the first time I compile the game, the penguin image might load properly, then I will stop the build and recompile it, and the penguin will no longer show up this time, then if I stop it and rebuild it, the penguin might be visible once again, and so on....

This how I implement my particle emitters:

```
-(void)addFeathers: (CGPoint) position{
if (soundEnabled==TRUE) {
       [poofSound play];
}


NSString *explosionPath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FeatherAnimation1" ofType:@"sks"];
SKEmitterNode *explosion2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:explosionPath2];
explosion2.position = position;
[mainLayer addChild:explosion2];

SKAction *removeExposion2 = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:10],[SKAction removeFromParent]]];
[explosion2 runAction:removeExposion2];

}
```

then later in the program:

```
if([characterName isEqualToString:@"penguin"]){
       [self addFeathers:deadPos];
    }
```

**The project can be found at the following link: https://github.com/cyrusbehr/Dodge.git**

I understand this application was made with bad programming practice, but it was just my first one. I would really like to resolve these issues so I can put the game back on the appstore!

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the images into the assets catalogue;
this is because the method:

```
+ (instancetype)spriteNodeWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name;
```

name is the name of an image file stored in the app bundle.

Add ".png" will be ok.

Comment: Ok i will give it a try, just to confirm, where should i be adding the suffix .png?

Comment: `[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"aaPenguin@2x.png"];`

and just consider add @3x image

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but I still seem to be having the issue where the images only sometimes load

Comment: too many image to change, just for example. I put "penguin" to Images.xcassets, and then add @3x to it. Run in iPhone 6 Plus, it can show on the main window. So, maybe you should add 1x,2x,3x to each pic.

Comment: I did a bit of debugging and changed the name "penguin" to an image file that doesn't exist, and the strange thing is that sometimes when i compile it I will get the square icon with the x , meaning that the file with that given name was not located, but other times, this error box will not even show up. The strange thing is that even if this error box does not show up (meaning the program did not try to locate the image file), the hit detection still woks and the "invisible" penguin can still die

Comment: I resolved the issue, please refer to my answer for the solution. Thank you for all the help you provide me with.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the images into the assets catalogue?

Comment: I tried putting all of my images in my Images.xcassets folder, but this did not seem to resolve the problem. Do I need to do any form of configuration (or change any code) other than just dragging the images into the Images.xcassets folder?

Comment: You dont. If you call the image in the asset catalogue "Player" than you just call it like so SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player") and it will automatically fetch the correct image (@2x, @3x) image. Apple recommends using asset catalogues for best performance and organisation.

Comment: In regards to your problem, its hard to judge from looking at the code. You got any idea which line could cause the problem?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, is there any chance you could look at the code from the github repo I have posted. I do not have much experience developing applications but would be very grateful if I can get this application to work once again.

Comment: I resolved the issue, please refer to my answer for the solution. Thank you for all the help you provide me with.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that after the XCode update, my background image was blocking my other nodes. I resolved this issue by changing the z-position of the background.

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sampleBackground"];
background.zPosition = -1.0;
```